# 2 Wi-Fi connections, one at 2.4 and one at 5 GHz

Tags: wifi-configuration, dual-band

Since I'm using a dongle to receive 5GHz Wi-Fi, I seem to be able to use 2 networks at the same time, one at 2.4GHz and one at 5GHz.

Now I wonder, what does my computer do when I'm connected to both bands on my router? Does this increase or decrease my connection-speed? Will this make my connection more or less stable? Are there any other problems this could establish?

Thank you.

Jonathan

Comment: It’s *very* unlikely to have two radios in a WiFi client. Especially with USB, there’s probably not even enough power for that.

Comment: There's no way you're connected to both channels at the same time.

Comment: I am, I have a USB device and a build-in Wi-Fi receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, it will automatically prioritize network connections (binding order). You can see which one has priority by running "netstat -rn" at the command prompt.   The interface with the lowest number is the one with the highest priority and the one that Windows will try first.

There are software solutions like [Speedify](http://speedify.com/) that claim to be able to bond multiple connections together, but I've never tried it.   I'm not sure if you'll notice much difference anyway unless you have a ton of bandwidth on your Internet connection or are moving huge files across your network.

Comment: Thank you. It's using my 2.4GHz receiver.

I'm going to check Speedify and see if it increases my network stability. Huge problem here, the whole street is interfering with my 2.4GHz signal and the walls seem to be a bit too thick for 5GHz, so gaming is really unstable. :-(

If anyone found this using Google, ignore the 'Software Loopback Interface 1' line.

Comment: Is bridging the connections an option?

Comment: My guess is that it won't work for your needs.   I'm you are probably getting latency and/or packetloss due to the interference on 2.4 and walls on 5ghz.   Binding the two connections together won't fix the signal reaching your NICs.  
How far away if your computer from the router?  Have you considered looking into powerline adapters?

Comment: Too bad. About 3 meters, in the hall. I recently checked how much interference there was with other networks a while back using inSSIDer. Lets say it's less than healthy. Somehow 5GHz is a lot faster, but 2.4GHz is more stable. Yes, I have considered Powerline, but we already have 2 adapters for our TV, so I doubt that it will increase our stability. Crap, I tried to bridge them, internet connection dropped and it's been busy deleting it for 15 minutes now.

Comment: Message editted. Nevermind about the deleting, done now :-)

Comment: Bridging is used to connect a wired device to your laptop so it can  use it's WiFi or vice versa.  As you saw, it won't help your situation.  :)   I'm assuming an ethernet run is out of the question.  Just to make sure, you updated the firmware on your router and have the latest drivers for your 5hz dongle?   What does inSSIder show for your 5ghz connection?

Comment: I see! :) Indeed, ethernet is out of the question. Drivers and firmware are op to date. 5GHz has a signal fluctuating between -58 and -65 dBm, somehow the fluctuation is incredibly stable. It says it's not overlapping anything and has a max rate of 216. 2.4GHz is between -50 and -55 with peaks of -59, overlapping 2, with a max rate of 193.

Comment: Powerline adapters are up to date too by the way.

Comment: What's your router and 5ghz adapter?

Comment: Also, have you tested your 5ghz connection on another computer?

Comment: My router is a TP-Link N900 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router and my receiver is a FRITZ!WLAN Stick AC 430.

Yes, slow on others computers too.

Comment: Okay, this is really weird, I seem to have internet for 5 seconds, then it drops for 5 seconds, comes back for 5 seconds, and so on. Could it be my beacon interval?

Comment: Not sure.   If possible, try a different router.   After that, you can start tweaking the settings but I'm out of ideas.  :)

Comment: Meh, that sucks! :( Thanks for your effort and time anyway! :)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that it could be a bug because I bridged and debridged it I guess...